# On Nash equilibrium in $2 \times 2 \times ... \times 2$ games.

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Let's say we have $n$-player game with 2 pure strategies available to each player, and we know for sure that this game has Nash equilibrium in totally mixed strategies. What would be good sufficient conditions for such game to have exactly one equilibrium in totally mixed strategies?

Comment: How general are the conditions you hoping/looking for?